# 文字列の奇数番目の文字をアスキコードをマイナス１した文字に変換するプログラムを作りたいです

Tags: swift, ios

文字列の全ての文字をアスキコードを
マイナス１した文字に変換するプログラムは作れたのですが、奇数番目の文字を変換するプログラムが作れませんでした。どのようにすれば良いか教えて頂きたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 出来ているプログラムを質問中に提示した方が回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Comment: 確認です。
iosとswiftのタグがついていますが、swiftを使って、ios上で動くプログラムの質問なのですか？

Answer (score 0):

対象文字列は ASCII コードのみの前提で、先頭を 0 番目（0 origin）として奇数番目の文字のみ文字コードを -1 するサンプルコードです。

```
let str = "abcdef"
var ss = ""
for (i, ch) in str.utf8.enumerated() {
    ss.append(String(UnicodeScalar(i % 2 == 1 && ch > 0 ? ch - 1 : ch)))
}
print(ss)  // "aaccee"
```